# React Redux Splice deleting only elements beyond index of 0

Tags: reactjs, redux

all I am creating a simple to-do list with react and redux. I am mapping over my items but for some reason, my onClick action will only delete items beyond index of 0. So I can delete my 2nd item I add to my list however, I can't delete items before that. Here is my code.

```
class TaskList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.tasks.map((task, taskId) => {
                    console.log("task", task)
                    console.log("id", taskId)
                    return (
                        <div key={taskId}>
                            {task}
                            <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteTask(taskId)}>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        tasks: state.tasks
    }
}

function dispatchStateToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({deleteTask: deleteTask}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchStateToProps)(TaskList)

const taskReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TASK': 
    state = state.concat(action.payload)
    break;
    case 'DELETE_TASK':
    state = state.splice(action.payload, 1)
    break;
  }
  return state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong.

You use the index of the item in the array as the key, instead you should generate an id for each todo you create, and then filter on that ID like this `state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload)` , it's explained in this [article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) and in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) (keys section).

The other thing is that the splice method is not pure as it changes the content of the array it's called on, also you seem to think that this methods returns the array of remaining elements when it actually returns an array with the removed elements.

So what happens when you delete the second element :

1. The splice method return an array containing the deleted element
   that you store in your state.
2. Later the `TaskList` receive this array containing only the deleted
   element.
3. `render` method of `TaskList` returns an array containing one React
   element with the key 0, the key hasn't changed so the reconciliation
   algorithm doesn't update the React Component, so the view for the
   first div doesn't change, the following div are removed.